# Can i use ajax to fetch data on click event of dynamically genrated button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i am working on asp.net web application.i use to generate button control dynamically more than once on a particular page.At the click event of that button i need to fetch data from sql server without refreshing entire page.As i am new to `Ajax` is it possible to use it with `Ajax`?

Comment: can i get any code sample for this?
Thanks in advance!!!!!!!1

Comment: There are a lot of resources already available for this type of question. Have you done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a typical ajax onclick call

http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php